# How to remove pointers after a ParseObject is deleted? Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have 2 classes in Parse, a User class and a Group class. The User class has a column that holds an array of pointers to the group class. Suppose I delete a Group object, how can I subsequently remove all pointers in the User class.

I know this is achievable in Parse Cloud code using the `beforeDelete` trigger but I'm not sure how to implement it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good reference to start with

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete("Group", function(request, response) {

// Ready to edit user
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("GroupsList", request.object);
query.include("Group");

query.each(function (user) {    
    //remove item from Groups List here which is equal to Group being deleted 
    return user.save();         
}).then(function() {    
    response.success();
}, function(error) {    
    response.error(error);
});
});
```

Check [parse.com](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions) cloud code guide to see how to push code to cloud

Answer (score 0):

`Parse.Object` class has a `remove()` method to remove a value from a column of type Array. So , you should use this method to remove the all `Group` entries from `User` with a `save()` call on it. As `User` get save delete `Group` object.